# Is a set of bounded functions bounded?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, convergence-divergence, metric-spaces

Please consider the following question (note that $C_b$ is the space of bounded continuous functions):

> Let $f_k$ be a convergent sequence in $\mathscr C_b(A, \mathbb R^m)$. Prove $\{f_k \mid k = 1,2,\ldots\}$ is bounded in $\mathscr C_b(A, \mathbb R^m)$.

If each $f_k$ is bounded, isn't it immediate then that the above set (let's call it S) is bounded, almost by definition? I don't believe the question is so trivial, so please explain what I am missing.

Comment: Consider the sequence of functions $f_k(x)=k$. All of these are bounded, continuous functions... You will need that it is a *convergent* sequence of functions.

Comment: @Clayton Ah okay, I see. Could you confirm that this is really what I need to show:   there exists $M\in \mathbb R$ such that for each $f \in S$ and for each $x \in A$,  $||f(x)|| \leq M$.     (where the norm is just the norm in $\mathbb R^m$)

Comment: That is correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. It is not automatic (consider the constant functions $g_k : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ given by
$$
g_k(x) = k \quad \forall x\in \mathbb{R}
$$
Each function is bounded, but the collection is not).

In this case, since $f_k \to f$, then for $\epsilon = 1$, there is a $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that
$$
\sup_{x\in A}|f_n(x) -  f(x)| < 1 \quad\forall n\geq N
$$
Hence, for $n \geq N$,
$$
\sup_{x\in A}|f_n(x)| \leq \sup_{x\in A}|f(x)| + 1 =: M
$$
Now let
$$
M' = \max\{ \sup_{x\in A}|f_k(x)| : 1\leq k\leq N\}
$$
then $\max\{M,M'\}$ is a bound for all $f_n$.