# Bounded derivative implies bounded function?

Tags: general-topology, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence, metric-spaces

[image]

By the following theorem, it suffices to show that $\{F_n: n\in\mathbb N\}$ is equicontinuous and bounded:

> If $f_k$ is a sequence in an equicontinuous and pointwise bounded set of maps from a compact metric space to $\mathbb R^m$, then $f_k$ has a uniformly convergent subsequence.

I have already shown that the set is equicontinuous. Now how do I show that $\{F_n: n\in\mathbb N\}$ is also bounded? (The fundamental theorem of calculus guarantees that each $F_n$ is bounded.)

Does my problem reduce to finding an $M'$ independent of $n$ and $x$ such that $|F_n(x)|\leq M'$, given that $|F_n'(x)|\leq M$ where $M$ is a constant?

P.S. I initially wanted to try proving that $F_n$ is convergent, but Kahen has pointed out that $F_n$ doesn't necessarily converge.

Comment: You'll need to use the fact that the $f_n$'s are *uniformly* bounded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something, then a bound for every $F_n$ is as follows. Where $M$ is the upper bound of every $f_n$:

$$F_n(x)=\int^x_af_n(t)dt\leq\int^x_aMdt=\frac{M}{2}x^2\leq\frac{M}{2}(b-a)^2$$

Note that that bound does not depend on $n$.

Comment: That each $F_n$ is bounded doesn't imply that the set ${F_n}$ is too; and since as Kahen pointed out $F_n$ may not converge, we can't use its convergence to show that the set is bounded either.

Comment: @Ryan I think I must be misunderstanding what *bounded set* means. I took it to mean that there exists a function that simultaneously bounds every function in the set.

Comment: Hey, you could perhaps refer to my previous question   http://math.stackexchange.com/q/511086/21813

Comment: Your suggestion together with the outline I gave in the last second sentence of my post above combines to give the desired proof. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: You'll want to appeal to Arzelà–Ascoli to show that $\{F_n \in C[a,b] : n \in \mathbb N\}$ is precompact in $C[a,b]$. This will furnish you with your desired convergent subsequence.

Note that the $F_n$ don't necessarily converge. Consider

$\displaystyle\qquad
f_n(x) = \begin{cases} 
  0 & \text{if } n \text{ is even} \cr
  1 & \text{if } n \text{ is odd}
\end{cases}
$

Comment: @Ryan Each $f_n$ is bounded by, say $M$, so each $F_n$ is bounded by the integral of $M$, which is bounded by whatever the value of that is at $b$. Something like $M/2(b-a)^2$ I should think. Or am I missing somethiing?

Comment: Oh, thanks for pointing out my mistaken thinking. I don't really understand your hint. Don't I just need to show that $\{F_n\}$ is bounded (uniformly or pointwise doesn't matter, as in this instance one implies the other) to complete my proof?